# HQL querying columns in a set

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Is it possible to reach the individual columns of table2 using HQL with a configuration like this?

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class table="table1">
    <set name="table2" table="table2" lazy="true" cascade="all">
      <key column="result_id"/>
      <many-to-many column="group_id"/>
    </set>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

They're just properties of table1's table2 property.

```
select t1.table2.property1, t1.table2.property2, ... from table1 as t1
```

You might have to join, like so

```
select t2.property1, t2.property2, ... 
    from table1 as t1
    inner join t1.table2 as t2
```

Here's the relevant part of the [hibernate doc](http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select).

Answer (score 1):

You can query on them, but you can't make it part of the where clause.  E.g.,

```
select t1.table2.x from table1 as t1
```

would work, but

```
select t1 from table1 as t1 where t1.table2.x = foo
```

would not.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say table2 has a column "`color varchar(128)`" and this column is properly mapped to Hibernate.

You should be able to do something like this:

```
from table1 where table2.color = 'red'
```

This will return all `table1` rows that are linked to a `table2` row whose `color` column is 'red'.  Note that in your Hibernate mapping, your `set` has the same name as the table it references.  The above query uses the name of the *set*, **not** the name of the table.